# How to refer to a resource in Terraform when the resource name is specified?

Tags: terraform

I have a question about terraform referral. For example we have a resource defined as

```
resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "example" {
  name   = "role_policy"
```

According to the terraform documentation the resource referral should be

```
<TYPE>.<NAME>
```

What will be the NAME for referral for the resource in this case:

```
example
```

or

```
role_policy
```

Comment: it will be role_policy

Comment: @SashoRistovski it is example, I just checked.  How to find a resource by name?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing:

```
aws_iam_role_policy.example.name
```

Will return a value “role_policy”.

If you want to reference the resource, for example in depends on block then you can use

```
aws_iam_role_policy.example
```

Comment: very interesting, thank you.  Can you please give an example how to reference a resource by the attribute name, in this case policy_name?

Comment: This is the first reference in my answer.

Comment: It refers to the value - not to the resource itself